# SQL. Left Join and Null value when column doesn't exists

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, left-join

I am stuck in a query. Hopefully someone can help me here.

I have these 4 tables:

Table: items

```
id_items
1
```

Table: items_atr_currencies_match

```
id_items_atr_currencies_match | id_items_atr_currencies | id_items
1                             | 1                       | 1
```

Table: items_atr_currencies_translations

```
id_items_atr_currencies_translations | id_items_atr_currencies | id_language_code | translation
1                                    | 1                       | 1                | $
```

Table: items_atr_currencies

```
id_items_atr_currencies
1
```

Table: languages

```
id_languages | language_code
1            | es
2            | en
```

My query:

```
SELECT
    id_items,
    iact3.translation AS currency

FROM
    items i

LEFT JOIN 
    items_atr_currencies_match AS iacm3 ON iacm3.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN 
    items_atr_currencies AS iac3 ON iac3.id_items_atr_currencies = iacm3.id_items_atr_currencies
LEFT JOIN 
    items_atr_currencies_translations AS iact3 ON iact3.id_items_atr_currencies = iacm3.id_items_atr_currencies 
LEFT JOIN 
    languages AS l ON l.id_languages = iact3.id_language_code OR iact3.id_language_code IS NULL

WHERE
    i.id_items = 1
    AND l.language_code = "en"
```

Expected result:

```
id_items | currency
1        | null
```

Getting 0 result instead

I guess I am missing something like "OR iact3.id_language_code does not exists" in the last LEFT JOIN but I don't know how to do it.

It works fine when the table items_atr_currencies_match doesn't have data or when the table items_atr_currencies_translations has the translation but not when there is data and the translation doesn't exists.

Thank you in advance

*** UPDATE ***

Finally this query is doing what I want:

```
SELECT 
     i.id_items,            
     iact3.translation AS currency

FROM
     items i

LEFT JOIN 
     languages AS l ON l.language_code = 'en'
LEFT JOIN 
     items_atr_currencies_match AS iacm3 ON iacm3.id_items = i.id_items
LEFT JOIN 
     items_atr_currencies_translations AS iact3 ON iact3.id_items_atr_currencies = iacm3.id_items_atr_currencies 
     AND l.id_languages = iact3.id_language_code            
LEFT JOIN items_atr_currencies AS iac3 ON iac3.id_items_atr_currencies = iacm3.id_items_atr_currencies

WHERE
    i.id_items = 1
```

All I had to do is move the language LEFT JOIN to the fist place and check the language code there.

Comment: You probably need to move the last condition into the join: `LEFT JOIN 
    languages AS l ON l.id_languages = iact3.id_language_code AND l.language_code = "en" 

WHERE
    i.id_items = 1`. The basic rule for Outer Joins: conditons on the outer table are usually part of WHERE and conditions on the inner table are added to `ON`

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, I get the result "1  | $ " but the "en" translation doesn't exits. Shouldn't get the 1  | null instead? That's the results I am expecting. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move condition `AND l.language_code = "en"` into the left join. Otherwise, the this condition will be checked after all left joins have been evaluated, and if then the resulting tuple does not have `language_code = "en"`, it will be eliminated from the overall result.

If you now want that `currencies_translations` are only considered if they map to a valid language, than you have to connect `currencies_translations` and `languages` by a join before "left-joining" it together with the overal result:

```
...
LEFT JOIN (select iact3.id_items_atr_currencies as iact3id from
    items_atr_currencies_translations AS iact3 JOIN 
    languages AS l ON (l.id_languages = iact3.id_language_code AND l.language_code = "en") OR iact3.id_language_code IS NULL) as iact3l 
    ON iact3l.iact3id = iacm3.id_items_atr_currencies
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @stepahnLechner, now I get results but I'm not getting the right result. I get: ` id_items | currency` ` 1 | $` and since that translation doesn't exists I was expecting: ` id_items | currency` ` 1 | null`, any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: I suppose you have to treat `currencies_translations` and `languages` as a "joint intermediate result", which can then be  considered by the overal query as a left joint. See edited answer. Hope it works directly or with some slight syntax modifications...

Comment: ... And the "$" is in the result because there actually exists an `items_atr_currencies_translations`-entry, which is not filtered out because its (not existing) connection to `language` is just "left joined"...

Comment: Hi @Stephan, your answer still giving me the same result, however I have found the solution. I'm gonna update my answer and accept your as right to thank you for your information and help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a series of `left join`s.  When you have a condition in the `where` clause on any table *other than* the first table, then it tends to turn the `left join` into an `inner join`.  You need to put that condition in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT id_items,iact3.translation AS currency
FROM items i LEFT JOIN 
     items_atr_currencies_match AS iacm3
     ON iacm3.id_items = i.id_items LEFT JOIN 
     items_atr_currencies AS iac3 
     ON iac3.id_items_atr_currencies = iacm3.id_items_atr_currencies LEFT JOIN 
     items_atr_currencies_translations AS iact3
     ON iact3.id_items_atr_currencies = iacm3.id_items_atr_currencies  LEFT JOIN 
     languages AS l
     ON (l.id_languages = iact3.id_language_code OR iact3.id_language_code IS NULL) AND
        l.language_code = 'en' 
WHERE i.id_items = 1;
```

Conditions on the first table go in the `WHERE` clause.

Note:  I think the last condition can be simplified to:

```
     ON l.id_languages = iact3.id_language_code AND
        l.language_code = 'en'
```

The `LEFT JOIN` will include the row even if there is no match.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I get results but I'm not getting the right result.

I get:

` id_items | currency`
` 1           | $`

and since that translation doesn't exists I was expecting:


` id_items | currency`
` 1           | null`

Thanks